# Rails 5 - Google Page Speed Insights - Leverage Browser Caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, browser-cache

I've got a Rails 5 development site running on a public server. The project is also in development mode. I have been scanning the site with Google Page Speed Insights and one of the largest suggestions has been to leverage browser caching. So, I looked around on google and every answer says to use this code:

```
config.public_file_server.headers = {
  'Cache-Control' => 'public, s-maxage=31536000, maxage=15552000',
  'Expires' => "#{1.year.from_now.to_formatted_s(:rfc822)}"
}
```

Because the project is in development mode I put this code in my development.rb file rather than production.rb. I haven't been able to get any different results by doing this. No errors either. I could use some guidance! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing a rails server in development is like trying to empty the oceans of water. The main changes in the production environment are performance enhancing configurations (caching, class reloading, asset compilation, etc).

I'd suggest copying the default production configurations over to your development config if you want to test performance in development mode. This will probably make development painful for you, however.

Or switch environments to production.

What's your real goal here?

Comment: I've already got the site running in production on another server so I have been able to identify the weak points (browser caching). So, I figured that if I could fix the browser caching in development then I would be able to easily transfer that code to work as expected in production and fix the browser caching.

Comment: Check out the official rails documentation for caching in development: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#caching-in-development

Comment: I got everything to work in development with the guide you sent earlier. Dropped the code I posted in the original question to the production.rb, restarted everything and the expiration and max ages aren't set. Is there another config or something required for production? I do have this line of code in my production.rb file also. config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

Comment: How are you serving assets? Does your rails app sit behind nginx or apache? The code in the original question is only for public files (assets, images, javascript). If you're serving them with nginx/apache, these settings won't take effect.